# vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have an existing vue component that I already use in one Vue page. I have added it to new component. It works but I noticed strange errors in Chrome console. They do not appear on its original occurence. I have no idea why it occurs because I copied a relevant code from the first usage.

Date.vue:

```
<template>
  <span>{{ this.formatted }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import { show } from '@/utils/dateUtils';

export default {
  name: 'Date',
  props: {
    date: String,
    format: String,
  },
  computed: {
    formatted() {
      return show(this.date, this.format);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

New component:

```
<template>
  <Date :date="item.info.date" format="dynamicDate" /> &bull;
</template>

<script>
import Date from '@/components/atoms/Date.vue';
import ProfileLink from '@/components/atoms/ProfileLink.vue';

export default {
  name: 'ItemBox',
  components: {
    Date,
  },
```

Errors:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: _components_atoms_Date_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor"

found in

---> <ItemBox> at src/components/molecules/ItemBox.vue
   <GridLayout>
     <ItemList> at src/components/molecules/ItemList.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1839
Vue._init @ vue.runtime.esm.js:5008
VueComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js:5154
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ vue.runtime.esm.js:3283
./src/main.js @ main.js:78
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:853
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ Home.vue?1405:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:853
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: _components_atoms_Date_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor
at VueComponent.created (ItemBox.vue:63)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:4219)
at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js:5008)
at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:5154)
```

Comment: I have the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: It's a long time. I think i replaced a component that used this code. Probably.